# XPath how to find nested element on first level

Tags: xpath

I have following XML:

```
<article>
    <div class="class1">
        <span>Article header 1</span>
        <div>
            <span>Date</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        <span>Details</span>
        <div class="class3">
            <span>Number</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Price 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="class3">
        <span>Footer 1</span>
        <div>Footer details</div>
    </div>
</article>
<article>
    <div class="class1">
        <span>Article header 2</span>
        <div>
            <span>Date</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Price 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        <span>Details</span>
        <div class="class3">
            <span>Number</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="class3">
        <span>Footer 2</span>
        <div>Footer details</div>
    </div>
</article
```

And I want to select only DIV without class and only from first nesting level
In this case

```
    <div>
        <span>Price 1</span>
    </div>
```

and

```
    <div>
        <span>Price 2</span>
    </div>
```

Note that this div in first article is on 3 place but in second article is on 2 place

I tried to use

```
//div[not(@class)]
```

but it find all elements in article, not only from first nest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close to the right expression.
This will select what you are looking for:

```xml
article/div[not(@class)]
```

This `article/div` indicates the direct `div` child element of the top node `article`.